# Given $|x|=|y| = 1$, show that the intersection of two tangents to a unit circle at points $x$ and $y$ is $\frac{2xy}{x+y}$.

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

> Given $|x|= |y| = 1$, show that the intersection of two tangents to a unit circle at points $x$ and $y$ is $\frac{2xy}{x+y}$.

What would be the best place to start to attempt this problem?

What I know:
$x^2= x\overline{x} = 1 = y\overline{y}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Z $ be their intersection point. Then from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2115987/given-x-1-show-that-the-equation-of-a-tangent-to-the-unit-circle-at-point), we know that $$z +x^2\bar z =2x \text {   and  } z+y^2\bar z =2y $$So $$(x^2-y^2)\bar z=2 (x-y)$$ $$\Rightarrow \bar z =\frac {2}{x+y} $$ Thus $z = \frac {2}{\bar x + \bar y} $. Since $x $ and $y $, lie on the unit circle, $$\bar x =\frac{1}{x} \text {    and   } \bar y = \frac {1}{y} $$ and the result follows. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For an alternative, more geometric proof, consider that the point of intersection $z$ must lie on the bisector of angle $\angle xoy$ by symmetry, so $z = \lambda(x+y)$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}\,$.

The [power of point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) $z$ with respect to the unit circle is $|z|^2-1$ and, since $zx$ is a tangent, it also equals $|z-x|^2$.
Therefore, using $\,\bar x = 1/x\,$ and $\,\bar y = 1/y\,$ at the last step, since $|x|=|y|=1\,$:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
z \bar z -1 & = (z-x)(\bar z - \bar x) \\
\cancel{z \bar z} -1 & = \cancel{z \bar z} - z \bar x - \bar z x + x \bar x \\
z \bar x + \bar z x & = 2 \\
 \lambda(x+y)\bar x + \lambda (\bar x + \bar y) x & = 2
\end{align}
$$
$$
 \lambda = \frac{2}{x \bar x + \bar x y+\bar x x +x \bar y} = \frac{2}{2 + \frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}} = \frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2+2xy} = \frac{2xy}{(x+y)^2}
$$

Then $z = \lambda (x+y)=\cfrac{2xy}{x+y}\,$.